# Error when creating a static variable: 'expected identifier, found `(` '

Tags: rust

I am trying to create global variables but I got multiple compilation errors in the process.
First I tried this:

```
static mut (tx, rx): (mpsc::Sender<bool>, mpsc::Receiver<bool>) = mpsc::channel();
```

```
error: expected identifier, found `(`

|
109 | static mut (tx, rx): (mpsc::Sender<bool>, mpsc::Receiver<bool>) = mpsc::channel();
                 ^
|
```

Then I have tried some other forms but it seems that they always give me a similar error:

```
thread_local!(static mut (tx, rx): (mpsc::Sender<bool>, mpsc::Receiver<bool>) = mpsc::channel());
```

```
error: no rules expected the token `(`

|
109 | thread_local!(static mut (tx, rx): (mpsc::Sender<bool>, mpsc::Receiver<bool>) = mpsc::channel());
                               ^
|
```

Finally, and in case this helps others to respond, it also happens with this:

```
static (x, y, z) = (1, 2, 3);
```

```
error: expected identifier, found `(`

    |
109 | static (x, y, z) = (1, 2, 3);
    |        ^
```

Maybe it is some error when creating the tuples from a static declaration, but I'm new to Rust, so I do not know if this is true.

Comment: `static` does not take a pattern

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you well found out in your last attempt, the same issue can be reproduced more easily:

```
static (A, B): (i32, i32) = (1, 2);
```

According to the Rust reference, the grammar for a static binding is defined as thus:

```
static_item : "static" ident ':' type '=' expr ';' ;
```

Mutable statics, although not included, is most likely defined to include 
`mut` after `static`:

```
mut_static_item : "static" "mut" ident ':' type '=' expr ';' ;
```

The compiler fails to parse your statement because it expects an *identifier*, not a *pattern*. This contrasts with `let` binding declarations, which accept a pattern after the keyword `let`:

```
let_decl : "let" pat [':' type ] ? [ init ] ? ';' ;
init : [ '=' ] expr ;
```

On this end, you have no choice but not to use patterns to declare static or const variables.

In your former case of `mpsc` channels, even this limitation would not solve your problem, since static bindings contain many other restrictions: consider for instance the declaration of a static `Vec`:

```
static moo: Vec<i32> = Vec::with_capacity(10);
```

This would yield the following error:

```
error[E0015]: calls in statics are limited to struct and enum constructors
 --> src/main.rs:1:24
  |
1 | static moo: Vec<i32> = Vec::with_capacity(10);
  |                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Channels are meant to be created locally and their endpoints sent to other threads from there. The documentation on the [`mpsc`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/sync/mpsc/index.html) module provides some examples.

Comment: Thanks for your help again, I use mpsc locally, but I wanted to do some tests and I found the previous "error", but now it becomes clear to me what can be static